# Django: Passing model object name through url

Tags: python, django

I want pass model name as parameter to  views.py
But it does not woork very well
Please guide me how to do this  Thank you

when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/filter/image/party/`
There is error said :

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'objects'
```

but the terminal can print mm='Party'

Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Party(models.Model):  
     ....
class Fun(models.Model):  
     ....
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^image/(?P<model>\w+)/$', views.object_list_1 ),
```

views.py:

```
def object_list_1(request, model):
    mm =  model.capitalize()
    obj_list = mm.objects.all()        
    template_name = 'filterimgs/%s_list.html' % mm.lower()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'object_list': obj_list, 
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure why you think this would work: just calling `capitalize()` on a string doesn't magically transform it into a model class.

You'll need to look up the actual class by its name in Django's model registry. Luckily, there is a function for that: `get_model`.

```
from django.db.models.loading import get_model
cls = get_model(app_name, model)
obj_list = cls.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should map the `model` name to model class.

One way is using `getattr` to get model instance from app module.

```
from app_name import models

def object_list_1(request, model):
    mm =  model.capitalize()
    cls = getattr(models, mm)
    obj_list = cls.objects.all()
    template_name = 'filterimgs/%s_list.html' % mm.lower()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'object_list': obj_list,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or using explicit mapping:

```
name_to_model_class = {'Party': Party, 'Fun': Fun}

def object_list_1(request, model):
    mm =  model.capitalize()
    cls = name_to_model_class[mm]
    obj_list = cls.objects.all()
    template_name = 'filterimgs/%s_list.html' % mm.lower()
    return render_to_response(template_name, {'object_list': obj_list,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks you let me know the problem:'Party' and  Party is different